# Problem with dual wifi

Tags: wireless, ktorrent

I installed kubuntu 16.04.1 on my notebook ASUS R510VX-DM004D with dual wifi.
I can connect without problems to the 2'4Ghz network and it works properly, but when i try to connect at the 5Ghz network connects correctly but I can not navigate. If i try to do a ping (to google dns for example) does not respond.

I've been reading but can not find solution. Anyone with the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please only ask one question at the time. Create a new question for one of them, and edit that one out of the question above.

Comment: Done. thanx for the info.

Comment: output of ifconfig? Maybe your 5Ghz isn't konfigured correctly and I would guess Linux automatically preferes to use the 5Ghz connection if there is one

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.